# EIPAbstractError while creating Delphi TRestClient

Tags: rest, delphi

Not getting very far on this one as every example I see uses Form when I want to keep this a console application (will eventually).

The following code will crash everytime with an `EIPAbstractError: IPProcs is not defined. Make sure IPPeerCommon() is in the uses clauses`.

Adding that to the Uses clauses breaks with a `No peer with the interface guid [xxx-xx...]`

```
program EMV_ConsoleTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, REST.Client;

var
  LClient: TRESTClient;

begin
  try
    LClient := TRESTClient.Create('http://localhost:9000/');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding _IpPeerClient_, too?

Comment: @UweRaabe:  I recently had a similar problem with one of the DataSnap demos which was fixed by adding IpPeerClient to the Uses list of one of unit.

Comment: @UweRaabe THANKS. That fixed it.